# img src not working anywhere but _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, image, visual-studio-2022

I have a MVC project in visual studio 2022 and some images I want to display in *gallery.cshtml* file. Images are in the *images* folder in *wwwroot*. I want to use the simple code:

```
<img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="image1" />
```

but it doesn't display the image.
When I copy-paste the same code into *_Layout.cshtml*, it works.
How can I make the same code work in any *.cshtml* file and not only in *_Layout.cshtml*?

Comment: Always prefix with /  IE: _/images/imageX.jpg_

Comment: If your other cshtml files are in subfolders, then you need to mention in the `relative` path.

Comment: Refer to the 2 ways of setting the image `src` attribute, [here](https://www.jquery-az.com/html-img-src-image-source-attribute-with-path-possibilities-5-examples/)